# iOS Safari issue with Audio from Server

Tags: ios, html, audio, safari, mobile-safari

So currently working on a project and experiencing a strange issue with the ios version of Safari involving the playback of an audio file from a server.

I'm currently facing the following issue:

1. Person comes onto the page which has a standard html5 audio tag, and a direct link to the audio file for downloading purposes.
2. Person tries to listen to audio from audio tag, content plays for x number of minutes, cuts off then repeats (the x number of minutes is NOT the length of the recording, and is not consistent).
3. Person tries direct link of recording, rather then downloading the recording, Safari appears to go to a new page and wraps the download url in a video element, and the same issue as step 2 occurs.

Now the audio file is served up via a java scriptlet, which serves the file with the following code snippet:

```
String fn = saveTo + file_name;
f = new File(fn);

String fname = f.getName();
String contentType = "audio/wav";
if(fname.endsWith("mp3")){
    contentType = "audio/mp3";
}

response.setContentType(contentType);
response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename="+f.getName());
response.setHeader("Content-Length", ""+f.length());

FileInputStream fin = null;

try{
    fin = new FileInputStream(f.getCanonicalFile());

    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    int x = 0;

    while((x = fin.read(data, 0, 1024))>=0){
        response.getOutputStream().write(data, 0, x);
        Thread.sleep(1);
    }
} finally {
    if(fin != null) {
        try{
            fin.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){}
    }
}
```

Now I know the code isn't the best by any measure, it isn't my code, and we're obviously working on the assumption that the file is found.

I'm finding when debugging on the iPhone with debug mode on a mac, it doesn't seem to show a return status code. It shows no response headers but it obviously must be receiving something. The server log seems to think its returning a status 200, this showing in Chrome and Firefox.

The code above appears to work fine with Chrome, and Firefox, but not Safari.

The only thing I am guessing is it has something to do with how the file is being pushed to the output stream that Safari isn't liking, or maybe its getting confused and should have a different status code. I've been banging my head against this for a good few days, and reading as much as I can about Safari, though most of the documentation I'm finding is on its "unique" implementation of web audio, and the use of a single channel which seems to be irrelevant to this.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue with Safari on iOS, and after a lot of debugging, I found the issue was related to the combination of headers applied to the response.

My application is C#-based, but this solution should be platform independent (because as previously stated, it is a response header issue).

**Necessary Headers:**

- Content-Range: bytes 0-[content length]/[content length]
- Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
- Content-Length: [content length]
- Accept-Ranges: bytes

I devised this after inspecting a response from MP3s delivered via Akamai's content delivery service.

Comment: I sent these exact headers but the problem persisted for me

Comment: @Leon : I can only suggest that you inspect a response from another service that functions well with Safari, and inspect their headers. I experienced this issue 3 years ago, so perhaps newer versions of Safari (iOS) require different headers?